# Environment variables in .git/config

Tags: git, git-config

I have a git repo created with the `--serparate-git-dir` option. I often use the same repo form different working trees by specifying `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` as arguments.

I have two working trees I switch between frequently so I added a `.git` file in the secondary work tree pointing to the repository directory. However since the repository's `config` file points to the primary working tree, I still have to specify it explicitly, otherwise it uses the primary working tree.

I tried setting the value of `worktree` to `$PWD` int the `.git/config` file but this causes the following error:
`fatal: Could not chdir to '$PWD': No such file or directory`

Is there a way to make `worktree` dynamic?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem in that I wanted to make my `~/.gitconfig` portable across platforms, so that I could use the same gitconfig on my Macbook and in my Linux VM. I needed `credential.helper` to be different depending on the platform.

I ended up writing a little `generate_gitconfig` script, and add it to my bashrc so that `~/.gitconfig` was generated automatically upon starting each shell session.

Writing your gitconfig via a script gives you more flexibility in that you can set values dynamically based on environment variables, whether certain commands are installed, the hostname of the machine, etc.

Here is my `generate_gitconfig` script, as an example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF > $HOME/.gitconfig
# This gitconfig was generated via ~/.bin/generate_gitconfig.
# Edit that file, not this one!

[user]
    name = Dave Yarwood
    email = dave.yarwood@gmail.com
[push]
    default = simple
[core]
    autocrlf = input
    editor = nvim
    excludesfile = $HOME/.gitignore_global
[rerere]
    enabled = true
EOF

if [[ "$(uname)" == Darwin ]]; then
  CREDENTIAL_HELPER="osxkeychain"
elif [[ -n "$(which gnome-keyring-daemon)" ]]; then
  CREDENTIAL_HELPER="/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring/git-credential-gnome-keyring"
fi

if [[ -n "$CREDENTIAL_HELPER" ]]; then
  cat <<EOF >> $HOME/.gitconfig
[credential]
  helper = $CREDENTIAL_HELPER
EOF
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 05-2016**
As @amynbe comments, git >= 2.5 has git-worktree https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

---

I have a script that someone on freenode passed around, I'm not sure of the author but I know I can share, it is used to create different working copyes based on branches, I think it could fit your use case:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

usage () {
        echo "usage:" $@
        exit 127
}

die () {
        echo $@
        exit 128
}

if test $# -lt 2 || test $# -gt 3
then
        usage "$0 <repository> <new_workdir> [<branch>]"
fi

orig_git=$1
new_workdir=$2
branch=$3

# want to make sure that what is pointed to has a .git directory ...
git_dir=$(cd "$orig_git" 2>/dev/null &&
  git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null) ||
  die "Not a git repository: \"$orig_git\""

case "$git_dir" in
.git)
        git_dir="$orig_git/.git"
        ;;
.)
        git_dir=$orig_git
        ;;
esac

# don't link to a configured bare repository
isbare=$(git --git-dir="$git_dir" config --bool --get core.bare)
if test ztrue = z$isbare
then
        die "\"$git_dir\" has core.bare set to true," \
                " remove from \"$git_dir/config\" to use $0"
fi

# don't link to a workdir
if test -h "$git_dir/config"
then
        die "\"$orig_git\" is a working directory only, please specify" \
                "a complete repository."
fi

# don't recreate a workdir over an existing repository
if test -e "$new_workdir"
then
        die "destination directory '$new_workdir' already exists."
fi

# make sure the links use full paths
git_dir=$(cd "$git_dir"; pwd)

# create the workdir
mkdir -p "$new_workdir/.git" || die "unable to create \"$new_workdir\"!"

# create the links to the original repo.  explicitly exclude index, HEAD and
# logs/HEAD from the list since they are purely related to the current working
# directory, and should not be shared.
for x in config refs logs/refs objects info hooks packed-refs remotes rr-cache svn
do
        case $x in
        */*)
                mkdir -p "$(dirname "$new_workdir/.git/$x")"
                ;;
        esac
        ln -s "$git_dir/$x" "$new_workdir/.git/$x"
done

# now setup the workdir
cd "$new_workdir"
# copy the HEAD from the original repository as a default branch
cp "$git_dir/HEAD" .git/HEAD
# checkout the branch (either the same as HEAD from the original repository, or
# the one that was asked for)
git checkout -f $branch
```

Comment: So I get that there is no  way to use an environment variable in that `config` file? I will definitely give that script a try, I hope it works well under Git for windows

Comment: from what I know, no, you can't set an env var in a config file, given it has the absolute path relative to your working dir, this posted is another viable solution, I hope it suits your needs anyway!

Comment: Superseded by the git-worktree command added in Git 2.5. See http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/